# Hidden divblock comes back when using ajax request - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, concurrency, synchronization

I've encountered a strange issue in jquery and it follows here ...

When the customer enters his email ajax makes a query to the db to look if the customer data is stored there. If NOT a new div block pops up

```
 $('#cust_date_of_birth').css('display', 'block');
```

This divblock contains among other a checkbox where the customer can enter his customerdata manually. This goes through the following function (listener)

```
    //checkbox for manual input
    $('#checkbox1').change(function() {

        if($(this).is(":checked")) {

            $('#customer_data_field').css('display', 'block');              
            $('#cust_date_of_birth').css('display', 'none');

        } else {
            $('#customer_data_field').css('display', 'none');
    }

    });
```

So - when the customer checks the checkbox - two things happends

- a customer data field shows up where he or she can enter customerdetails.
- the actual divblock,in which this checkbox is part is (supposed to) be hidden.

But now comes the strange thing ...

After having entered the email-address and the new divblock (cust_date_of_birth) shows .. checking the checkbox **too fast** the cust_date_of_birth-field is only hidden for some hundred milliseconds and then comes back - despite the css('display', 'none') function is called.
But **if** one waits a couple of seconds to check it - everything works just fine.

More - this is true for chrome webbrowser. Firefox is ok.

Is this about concurrency or something? Should functions be syncronized or what could be done to solve this?

**html**

```
<div id="cust_date_of_birth" style="display:none;">
        <p>
            <span id = "dob_text">We could not find you in our system - please either enter your social secirut number or enter customer details manually.</span>
        </p>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>social security number</td>
                <td><input id="cust_dob_inputid" type="text" size="18" value="" enabled> </input> </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <span style="color:grey">enter your socialsecurity number to get data fast</span> <br><br>

        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>enter your customer details manually</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should wait to the ajax request is finished. Theres a listener you can add to the document called **ajaxComplete**

```
 $( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
   $( ".log" ).text( "Triggered ajaxComplete handler." );
 });
```

So in your case:

```
 //checkbox for manual input
$('#checkbox1').change(function() {

    if($(this).is(":checked")) {

      $( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
         $('#customer_data_field').css('display', 'block');              
         $('#cust_date_of_birth').css('display', 'none');
      });

    } else {
        $('#customer_data_field').css('display', 'none');
}

});
```

As soon as the ajax request is finished - the invoked eventhandler is called.

Please see the documentation ---> http://api.jquery.com/ajaxcomplete/